# redirect all pages with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've been looking to find a solution for this problem but I believe I'm not asking the right question so I'll explain it in detail here.

I built a new HTML site and I want to redirect the old domain which was a PHP site to the new domain which is going to be a HTML site. URL structure is same but file format is changed.

I need a .htaccess code that redirects all pages from old domain to pages of the new domain.

for example: oldsite.com/contact.php ===> newsite.com/contact.html

any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this rule to the htaccess file in your oldsite.com's document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ http://newsite.com/$1.html [L,R=301]
```